# How can i make a secure createQuery in a generic method in Java?

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following generic method in my own Persistence-class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T getByCondition(Class<T> clazz, String database, Object id){
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager(database);
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM "+clazz.getName()+" t WHERE t.id = :id").setParameter("id", id);
    T result = (T) q.getSingleResult();
    return result;
}
```

The method works pretty fine, but I am concerned about the `"+clazz.getName()+"` in the Query as I am not very sure if this could lead to an sql-injection.

Is there a better way to declare the Class I want to search for **in the Query**?

Thanks in advance for your answers. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've posted is safe, as the class [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) is final and can't be extended and is inexorably tied to the class it represents which means you won't be able to pass it a fake class where `getName()` returns a custom string, furthermore you cannot have a class name which includes the punctuation necessary to use SQL injection. e.g., this is impossible:

```
class ' or '1'='1; DROP TABLE USERS; --
```